# Deriving a formula for average torque on a uniform metal rod with pivot point L from the edge of any side

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

Okay, this is most likely incorrect since I only have a prerequisite of algebra-based physics and did not take any calculus-based physics yet. I have however taken Calculus 1 and 2 and am quite proficient. I was wondering if there was a formula I could derive to find the average torque of a rod given the radius of the cross-section, the length away from the pivot point, and the density (to calculate mass). I created these diagrams

[image: diagram]

I decided to find the volume of the rod first by finding the area of the cross section and integrating it between 0 to L, like this

$$\pi\int_0^L r^2dx$$
$$V=\pi[xr^2]_0^L$$
Since 0 just cancels out then
$$V=\pi(Lr^2)$$

However this is where I begin to over step my bounderies. My thought process is that since torque is dependant on force, then we must know the mass of the rod over length L. Using density we can solve for mass and get the following equation:

$$m=\pi dLr^2$$
d=density, L=length from center to edge, r= radius of cross section

Then I solved for average force by multiplying by 9.8
$$F_{avg}=9.8\pi dLr^2$$

This is where I get more confused though because the length is changing. I wanted to plug this average force back into my $\tau=F_{avg}L$ but since L is changing I wasn't sure whether to integrate that as well or to leave it. I decided to just plug it back into my torque equation and I came up with this formula:

$$\tau=9.8\pi dL^2r^2$$

I just want someone more experienced in this subject to explain why this is not correct... or possibly correct. I am just confused. Please share some insight.

Comment: Are you referring to the torque created by the uneven distribution of mass due to the position of the pivot?

Comment: @LienardWeichert Yes

Answer (score 0):

To calculate torque due to a force, you need a location relative to the pivot for that force vector.  For weight, you can do it two ways.  One is to divide the rod into many pieces, each with its own position providing a portion of the torque around the pivot.  You can then add all torques together.  The other way has done most of the work for you.  If you count "g" as constant for the object, then a single weight vector at the object's center of mass will work correctly around any pivot.

As a personal introduction bypassing the complexity of calculus, consider a massless rod with a mass at each end.  Make them different masses.  Orient the rod horizontally on a pivot at the center.  First, calculate the two individual opposing torques and combine them.  Since they are in opposing directions, you would subtract the magnitudes.Second, find the location of the center of mass and replace the single masses with one total mass at the center of mass position.  Calculate torque again.  You will find that the two situations yield the same torque so long as the pivot location at the center of the bar does not change.  Another interesting case is to place the pivot point at the center of mass.  Placing it at either end of the bar can also be quite fascination.